no matching package named `orml-vesting` found
I am trying to add orml-vesting in my project but I am getting error: no matching package named orml-vesting found issue while running cargo check -p node-template-runtime. Can somebody point out me the issue?
cargo clean && cargo update also not working.
Thank you.

Because it's using Cargo.dev.toml. Without a Cargo.toml, cargo can't find the package.
You can use it from crates.io directly.

https://github.com/open-web3-stack/open-runtime-module-library/blob/74cd466d75625cd1cd5645e9e89801b306fa2f3a/vesting/Cargo.toml#L6
https://crates.io/crates/orml-vesting/0.7.0

